# Any python package to speed up for loop computation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I have two lists `L` and `C`, both sorted from smallest to largest. `L` contains positive integers, `C` contains both positive integers and positive fractional numbers `(e.g. 0.01,0.05,..,100)`. Length of `C` is fixed at `6000+`, length of `L` is variable `(between 2 and 3000)`.

The goal is: given some constant `M`, find `l` from `L` and `c` from `C` s.t. `l*c<=M` and as close as possible to `M`.

Currently I'm using for loop over `C` and binary search over list `L` to find out the largest `l*c` which is `<=M`. However it is very slow.

```
candidate_list = []
for c in C:
    binary search on list L using while loop to find out the best l*c<=M
    candidate_list.append(best l*c)
print(max(candidate_list))
```

Given length of `L` to be `N`, using binary search will take `logN`. However, since length of `C` is `6000+`, for loop over `c` will be slow. And if I have multiple lists `L` with different lengths, using for loop will be very slow. May I know is there any numpy or scipy package to speed up calculation?

Note: Since I have many lists `L`, I can't just simply do numpy matrix multiplication between `L` and `C`_transpose and use `argmax` to find out the max `l*c` which is `<=M`.

Comment: If your loop is very large, try it by [pypy](https://pypy.org/)  instead of `python` (CPython)

Comment: If you are working with numerical data and not Python objects, [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) can generate very fast code, and can even automatically parallelize your loops if the iterations are independent from each other.

Answer (score 3):

Because both lists are sorted, it is enough to use **linear** algorithm:

Traverse one list in forward direction, find best pair for `item[A]` from the second list (say at index `K`)

For the next `item[A+1]` paired item definitely has smaller or equal index as previous (`K`), so you need **only one** run through  the second list.

Pseudocode:

```
 iL = len(L)-1
 for iC in range(len(C)):
     while L[iL] * C[iC] > M:
          iL -= 1
     use pair  L[iL], C[iC]
```

Comment: That is a nice observation. I added an answer with a sample implementation of this idea, and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

User @Mbo made a good point in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54666662/9225671):

> Traverse one list in forward direction and find best pair for `item[A]` from the second list, but starting the search from the back of the second list.
>   For the next `item[A+1]`, its pair item definitely has to be smaller or equal index as previous (K), so you need only one run through the second list.

Here is a sample implementation of the pseudocode he provides (**linear time** complexity, bound to the length of your largest list, which would be list C from your question):

```
def find(list_c, list_l, threshold):
    # all pairs of elements whose product is smaller than 'threshold'
    possible_pairs = []

    j = len(list_l) - 1
    for i in range(len(list_c)):
        while list_c[i] * list_l[j] > threshold:
            # product is too big, pick a smaller element from 'list_l'
            j -= 1

            if j < 0:
                # exit while loop
                break

        if j < 0:
            # exit for loop
            break

        # we store some extra info here
        possible_pairs.append({
            'c_index': i,
            'c_elem': list_c[i],
            'l_index': j,
            'l_elem': list_l[j],
            'product': list_c[i] * list_l[j],
        })

    print(possible_pairs)

    # return the pair with the biggest product (closest to threshold)
    return max(
        possible_pairs,
        key=lambda x: x['product'])
```

I also tested this solution:

```
import random

list_c = list(sorted(random.random()*100 for i in range(100)))
list_l = list(sorted(random.random()*100 for i in range(20)))
print('list_c', list_c)
print('list_l', list_l)

elem = find(list_c, list_l, threshold=50)

print('the best pair is')
print(elem)
```

The last print outputs something like:

```
{
    'c_index': 47,
    'c_elem': 46.42324820342966,
    'l_index': 0,
    'l_elem': 1.0709460533705695,
    'product': 49.716794448105375,
}
```

As you can see, a solution like this could be used to sequentially compute the search against many `L` lists that you mention in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also used some break condition inside my code actually. However, since there are 2000 L lists, and length of C is 6000+, if we use for loops, it will still be 2000*6000 iterations. Hence, running time is still pretty long..

Answer (score 0):

The [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) package. It is specifically designed to speed up python for loops.

From their website: Numba translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime using the industry-standard LLVM compiler library. **Numba-compiled numerical algorithms in Python can approach the speeds of C or FORTRAN.**